# proper syntax of getting wp-admin pages/links

Tags: paths

i cant seem to find the codex for my situation.

normally, i use `get_bloginfo('template_url')` to get to the template path, but this time i need to get to some **WP-ADMIN** pages.

i created a custom navigation bar on my `wp-admin` and everything is working fine. i just need to get the links for the ff:

- /wp-admin/upload.php
- /wp-admin/index.php
- /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page

what is the proper syntax `getting` the **path** to  these locations

```
get_bloginfo('admin_url')/wp-admin-upload.php // sample only, just to express my point.
```

Comment: `admin_url('filename.php');` should be appropriate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`admin_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url):

```
admin_url( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );
```